# Quitting telnet on Linux

Tags: linux, exit, telnet, mobaxterm

Standard escape character is CTRL-] on telnet.

https://superuser.com/questions/398/how-to-send-the-escape-character-on-os-x-terminal/427#427

says that on Hungarian keyboard it is CTRL-5.

On my student's terminal it works. On my terminal CTRL-5 displays

```
^[[1;5u
```

and does not go into the

```
telnet>
```

prompt. What setting hinders me to escape telnet this way?

EDIT: I omitted one key ingredient: I use MobaXTerm. I tried on putty and CTRL-5 worked with 5 from the alphanumeric keyboard. MobaXTerm might swallow CTRL-5.

Comment: Are you using an AZERTY keyboard? If so, have you tried Ctrl + $  ?

Comment: I am using a Hungarian keyboard

Comment: Would it anything to do with cooked vs raw modes?

Comment: You can give telnet the `-e` option to set the escape character to any single character you like.

Answer (score 7):

## Press the correct <kbd>5</kbd> key.

There are two <kbd>5</kbd> keys on your keyboard, one at position E05 and one on the numeric keypad, wherever that happens to be (either a separate keypad or an overlain keypad accessible with a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key or similar).  You are pressing the wrong one.

It does not matter that you have a Hungarian *keyboard*.  The engravings on the keytops do not control what actions the keys cause.  What matters is that you are using a Hungarian *keyboard mapping* such as `hu101.kmap` (on Linux operating systems).

In that keyboard mapping only one of the <kbd>5</kbd> keys produces the `␝` character in conjunction with the <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd> modifier, the key at position E05.  `␝` is of course the local escape sequence for the `telnet` program.

In that keyboard mapping the other <kbd>5</kbd> key, on the numeric keypad, produces the XTerm control sequence CSI `1` `;` `5` `u` that you are seeing; which denotes the <kbd>5</kbd> key on the numeric keypad, in "application mode", occurring once, with the <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd> modifier.

As the Hungarian keyboard map says:

```
    control keycode   6 = Control_bracketright
…
keycode  76 = KP_5
```